# Why do I keep getting datatype mismatch errors in sqlite3

Tags: sqlite, runtime-error, sqldatatypes

I keep getting datatype mismatch errors when running the following lines in sqlite3. I will include all of it from db creation to where I get the error.

```
CREATE TABLE PilotAirlines (
...> PilotID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
...> FName TEXT,
...> LName TEXT,
...> JobTitle TEXT,
...> Salary REAL,
...> AirlineID INTEGER,
...> NPlanes TEXT,
...> NRoutes TEXT,
...> NPilots TEXT,
...> FOREIGN KEY (AirlineID) REFERENCES Airlines (AirlineID)
...> );
CREATE TABLE Airlines (
...> AirlineID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
...> NPlanes TEXT,
...> NRoutes TEXT,
...> NPilots TEXT
...> );
INSERT INTO Airlines (AirlineID, NPLanes, NRoutes, NPilots)
...> VALUES
...> (1, 130, 75, 50),
...> (2, 200, 90, 85),
...> (3, 250, 125, 105);
INSERT INTO PilotAirlines (PilotID, FName, LName, JobTitle, Salary, AirlineID, NPLanes, NRoutes, NPilots)
 VALUES
 ...> ('P00100', 'John', 'Hancock', 'Pilot', 110000, 1, NULL, NULL, NULL),
 ...> ('P00101', 'Sally', 'Smith', 'CoPilot', 95000, 2, NULL, NULL, NULL),
 ...> ('P00102', 'Nancy', 'Smith', 'Pilot', 115000, 3, NULL, NULL, NULL),
 ...> ('P00103', 'William', 'Hart', 'CoPilot', 85000, 1, NULL, NULL, NULL),
 ...> ('P00104', 'Jane', 'Doe', 'Pilot', 95000, 3, NULL, NULL, NULL);
Runtime error: datatype mismatch (20)
```

I thought maybe the AirlineID needed to be changed as I had a 'P' in the ID and that was supposed to be an INT so I changed it in the following. But it still resulted in an error.

```
INSERT INTO PilotAirlines (PilotID, FName, LName, JobTitle, Salary, AirlineID, NPLanes, NRoutes, NPilots)
...> VALUES
...> ('00100', 'John', 'Hancock', 'Pilot', 110000, 1, NULL, NULL, NULL),
...> ('P00101', 'Sally', 'Smith', 'CoPilot', 95000, 2, NULL, NULL, NULL),
...> ('00101', 'Sally', 'Smith', 'CoPilot', 95000, 2, NULL, NULL, NULL),
...> ('00102', 'Nancy', 'Smith', 'Pilot', 115000, 3, NULL, NULL, NULL),
...> ('00103', 'William', 'Hart', 'CoPilot', 85000, 1, NULL, NULL, NULL),
...> ('00104', 'Jane', 'Doe', 'Pilot', 95000, 3, NULL, NULL, NULL);
Runtime error: datatype mismatch (20)
```

Please help me with this!! It's probably an obvious answer but I'm having issues with this tonight and it's part of my project paper so please!!!!

Thank you all in advance!!

I thought maybe the AirlineID needed to be changed as I had a 'P' in the ID and that was supposed to be an INT so I changed it in the following. But it still resulted in an error.

```
 INSERT INTO PilotAirlines (PilotID, FName, LName, JobTitle, Salary, AirlineID, NPLanes,     NRoutes, NPilots)
...> VALUES
...> ('00100', 'John', 'Hancock', 'Pilot', 110000, 1, NULL, NULL, NULL),
...> ('P00101', 'Sally', 'Smith', 'CoPilot', 95000, 2, NULL, NULL, NULL),
...> ('00101', 'Sally', 'Smith', 'CoPilot', 95000, 2, NULL, NULL, NULL),
...> ('00102', 'Nancy', 'Smith', 'Pilot', 115000, 3, NULL, NULL, NULL),
...> ('00103', 'William', 'Hart', 'CoPilot', 85000, 1, NULL, NULL, NULL),
...> ('00104', 'Jane', 'Doe', 'Pilot', 95000, 3, NULL, NULL, NULL);
Runtime error: datatype mismatch (20)
```

Comment: datatype mismatch will only be the primary key if it is INTEGER PRIMARY KEY. Your attempts, according to what you have posted still have a line with P in the PilotId as per `...> ('P00101', 'Sally', 'Smith', 'CoPilot', 95000, 2, NULL, NULL, NULL),` see https://www.sqlite.org/rescode.html#mismatch

Answer (score 0):

The datatype mismatch has a single cause, that being when an attempt is made to assign a non integer value for a column that is defined explicitly or implicitly as INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (with or without AUTOINCRMENT) i.e. the column is an alias of the **rowid** table.

- other columns can store any type of value without this issue.
- see https://www.sqlite.org/rescode.html#mismatch

The attempts, according to the code you have shown still have a value that is not an integer value, as per:-

```
...> ('P00101', 'Sally', 'Smith', 'CoPilot', 95000, 2, NULL, NULL, NULL),
```

Correct this (change `'P00101'` to `'00101'` *(which is really 101 as an integer)*) and use:-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS PilotAirlines;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Airlines;
CREATE TABLE PilotAirlines (
    PilotID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    FName TEXT,
    LName TEXT,
    JobTitle TEXT,
    Salary REAL,
    AirlineID INTEGER,
    NPlanes TEXT,
    NRoutes TEXT,
    NPilots TEXT,
    FOREIGN KEY (AirlineID) REFERENCES Airlines (AirlineID)
);
CREATE TABLE Airlines (
    AirlineID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    NPlanes TEXT,
    NRoutes TEXT,
    NPilots TEXT
);
INSERT INTO Airlines (AirlineID, NPLanes, NRoutes, NPilots)
    VALUES
    (1, 130, 75, 50),
    (2, 200, 90, 85),
    (3, 250, 125, 105);
INSERT INTO PilotAirlines (PilotID, FName, LName, JobTitle, Salary, AirlineID, NPLanes, NRoutes, NPilots)
 VALUES
    ('00100', 'John', 'Hancock', 'Pilot', 110000, 1, NULL, NULL, NULL),
    ('00101', 'Sally', 'Smith', 'CoPilot', 95000, 2, NULL, NULL, NULL),
    ('00102', 'Nancy', 'Smith', 'Pilot', 115000, 3, NULL, NULL, NULL),
    ('00103', 'William', 'Hart', 'CoPilot', 85000, 1, NULL, NULL, NULL),
    ('00104', 'Jane', 'Doe', 'Pilot', 95000, 3, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

and then the result is :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS PilotAirlines
> OK
> Time: 0s


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Airlines
> OK
> Time: 0s


CREATE TABLE PilotAirlines (
    PilotID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    FName TEXT,
    LName TEXT,
    JobTitle TEXT,
    Salary REAL,
    AirlineID INTEGER,
    NPlanes TEXT,
    NRoutes TEXT,
    NPilots TEXT,
    FOREIGN KEY (AirlineID) REFERENCES Airlines (AirlineID)
)
> OK
> Time: 0.453s


CREATE TABLE Airlines (
    AirlineID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    NPlanes TEXT,
    NRoutes TEXT,
    NPilots TEXT
)
> OK
> Time: 0.042s


INSERT INTO Airlines (AirlineID, NPLanes, NRoutes, NPilots)
    VALUES
    (1, 130, 75, 50),
    (2, 200, 90, 85),
    (3, 250, 125, 105)
> Affected rows: 3
> Time: 0.024s


INSERT INTO PilotAirlines (PilotID, FName, LName, JobTitle, Salary, AirlineID, NPLanes, NRoutes, NPilots)
 VALUES
    ('00100', 'John', 'Hancock', 'Pilot', 110000, 1, NULL, NULL, NULL),
    ('00101', 'Sally', 'Smith', 'CoPilot', 95000, 2, NULL, NULL, NULL),
    ('00102', 'Nancy', 'Smith', 'Pilot', 115000, 3, NULL, NULL, NULL),
    ('00103', 'William', 'Hart', 'CoPilot', 85000, 1, NULL, NULL, NULL),
    ('00104', 'Jane', 'Doe', 'Pilot', 95000, 3, NULL, NULL, NULL)
> Affected rows: 5
> Time: 0.024s
```